# See only my text posts on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

How can I see only my text posts on Tumblr? I want to go back and see just my text posts, not the photos and things I reblogged. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that in the past this was possible but with a very recent change made it no longer work.

[This DailyDot article](http://www.dailydot.com/society/tumblr-help-tips-tricks-asks-guide/) explained how one could previously accomplish this:

> **8) Filter your dash by type by using "/show/[mediatype]".**
>
> Appending “/show/text” to tumblr.com will let you see only the text posts on your dash.
>
> This also works for photos, links, quotes, audio, chats, and videos.

(Though I'm unsure if this applied to user's blogs or just tumblr.com)

---

One way in which you could allow for this to work in the future is to tag all of your posts with their media type (e.g. #text, #image, #video, etc.) and then add `/tagged/text` (for example) to the end of your blog's URL to view only those types of posts.  You can use http://www.tumblr.com/mega-editor to easily add media-type tags to all of your old posts.

Comment: This no longer works the way the article describes. Instead the result is being displayed a 404 Not Found page by tumblr.

Answer (score 2):

You can view your text posts in the archive using the link below. Know more about filtering the archive in this [post](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/110181955200/now-you-can-filter-by-post-type-in-the-archive) by the Tumblr Staff.

`http://<username>.tumblr.com/archive/filter-by/text`

However, here's the catch: All your text posts will be retrieved, even the reblogged ones.

If you want to see your original posts, you can go to this [site](http://www.studiomoh.com/fun/tumblr_originals/) but all your posts will be retrieved (even photos, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [this search tool](http://boutofcontext.com/tumblr_backup.php).  It's really simple - just select the type of post (all, photo, text, etc.) and enter the user name and search.  I'd also use maybe 25 or 50 as the 'Return # per page,' rather than the default 500.  Sometimes, even when you enter the correct information, the search returns an error - you may have to try a few more times in order to get the results to display.

Comment: Please **do not** use URL shorteners here. They are unnecessary all-too-often mask spam, malware, or affiliate links.